# MySql Query issue in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a db table category_path 
it is in parent child relationship
and its look like this

```
-----------------------------
 id   |    parent_id
------------------------------
  1   |   NULL        
  2   |   1        
  3   |   2        
  4   |   1        
  5   |   3        
  6   |   2
```

using this table i want to create a new table which
will give me output like this.
Where the table below shows distance for each id from parent 0 to that id by traversing through its parent.

```
----------------------------------
   #  |id     | parent_id | distance    
----------------------------------
   1  |  1    |   1       |   0  
   2  |  1    |   2       |   1  
   3  |  1    |   3       |   2  
   4  |  1    |   4       |   1  
   5  |  1    |   5       |   3  
   6  |  1    |   6       |   2
   7  |  2    |   2       |   0
   8  |  2    |   3       |   1
   9  |  2    |   5       |   2
   10 |  2    |   6       |   1
   11 |  3    |   3       |   0
   12 |  3    |   5       |   1
   13 |  4    |   4       |   0
   14 |  5    |   5       |   0
   15 |  6    |   6       |   0
```

How to get this either by database query or by coding?

Comment: i want recursive query for it but i know that recursive query is not supported by MySql

Comment: As you note, MySQL doesn't support recursive functions so it is not well suited to this adjacency list model for storing hierarchical data. You ought to consider restructuring your data to use either nested sets or closure tables.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/623041) for more information.

Comment: select 
  *
from
  category_path i 
inner join category_path c on c.id = i.id
inner join category_path c2 on c.parent_id = c2.id
where
  c2.parent_id = @parentId

Comment: distance is generated on what basis?

Comment: is it compulsion to do with mysql query? you can do it by PHP script

Comment: If you're going to be dealing with tree-data a lot, check out [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Spending whole evening here is your solution:

```
function findValue($key,$src){

    return $src[$key];
}    

function inPatentList($val, $patent_list){

    return (in_array($val, $patent_list)) ? true : false;
}

function findFullTraverse($id, $src,&$str){
    if(0 != ($value = findValue($id, $src))){
        if($str==''){
            $str .= $value;
        }else{
            $str .= '_'.$value;
        }
        findFullTraverse($value,$src,$str);
    }
}
$id_parent = array(
    '1' => '0',
    '2' => '1',
    '3' => '2',
    '4' => '1',
    '5' => '3',
    '6' => '2',
);
$parent = array_values($id_parent);
$ids = array_keys($id_parent);

$depth = array();
$keys_for_value = array();
$id_parent = array_reverse($id_parent, true);
foreach($id_parent as $key => $val){

    $depth[] = $key.'_'.$key.'_0';
    if(inPatentList($key, $parent)){
        $keys_for_value = array_keys($id_parent, $key);
        $depth_found[$key] = $keys_for_value;
        foreach ($depth_found[$key] as $value){
            $str = '';
            findFullTraverse($value, $id_parent,$str);
            //echo $value.'=>'.$str.'<br/>';
            $traverse_array = explode('_', $str);
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($traverse_array);$i++){
                $has_depth = $i + 1;
                $depth[]=$traverse_array[$i].'_'.$value.'_'.$has_depth;
            }
        }
    }
}

sort($depth);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($depth);
echo '<pre>';
```

Hope this should work!!!

Comment: @M.I.T Does it solved your Problem? You may call it as backtracking. I have used recursion here. If you don't get let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use the Graph Engine, Its what its designed for 
http://openquery.com/products/graph-engine

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, (`id` - `parent_id`) as `difference` 
  from `category_path`...
```